# How to capture within an expression given as a string the resolvable terms using regex and then remove the terms that become 0 after operating on them

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, regex-group

```py
import re

#operation string (with parameters)
z_j_func = 'Z = 1 * 0 + 4 * 1/2 + 0 * 0 + 3 / 2 + M * 12 + M * 12 + M * 2 - 4 / 8'
```

Having a string like this which has parameters in some terms, how do I resolve the parameters without terms?, and then remove the terms that are 0 and join (by adding or subtracting) the terms that can be operated

```py
z_j_func = 'Z = 0 + 2 + 0 + 3 / 2 + M * 12 + M * 12 + M * 2 - 1 / 2'
```

In the end it should look like this:

```py
z_j_func = 'Z =  3 + M * 12 + M * 12 + M * 2'
```

Comment: This seems like a better fit for [sympy simplify](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sympy-simplify-method/) than RegEx.

Comment: Why not ask AI for a regex ?

Comment: @sln the regular expression that gpt creates is a little weird and doesn't work

Comment: @JRiggles try using this as an alternative because i can't use external libraries

Comment: @sln Presumably because they want a correct answer?

Comment: Is this the most complex string? Any other binary operators, potentially with different associativity rules, unary operators, functions, parentheses,... etc?

Comment: @trincot I only need for this operations, + - * / without associativity rules (not parenthesys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you would use a symbolic expression parser, like [`sympy`](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html).

Here is how that would work out, assuming that the string is of the form: `<identifier> = <expression>`

```
import sympy 

def simplify(equation):
    # Identify the operands of the equation
    left, right = equation.replace(" ", "").split("=")
    return f"{left} = {sympy.simplify(right)}"

# Example run
z_j_func = 'Z = 1 * 0 + 4 * 1/2 + 0 * 0 + 3 / 2 + M * 12 + M * 12 + M * 2 - 4 / 8'   
print(simplify(z_j_func))  # Z = 26*M + 3
```

If you prefer not to use a parser, but want to throw your own, then have a look at the next piece of code. It makes several assumptions, including:

- The input is of the form: `<identifier> = <expression>`;
- The expression does not have parentheses;
- The expression only uses the operators `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`;
- Where a `/` operator is used, it is the rightmost operator in the term;
- Unknowns (like `M`) only appear in numerators, not denominators

The code:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
from math import prod
from fractions import Fraction

def simplify(equation):
    # Identify the operands of the equation
    left, right = equation.replace(" ", "").split("=")
    
    # Identify the numerators and denominators
    terms = [
        term.split("/") if "/" in term else [term, 1]
        for term in re.split(r"\+|(?=-)", right)
    ]
    
    # Group terms by the unknowns (variable) in their numerators
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for num, denom in terms:
        d["*".join(re.findall(r"(?i)[a-z]+", num))].append(
            (re.sub(r"(?i)\*[a-z]+|[a-z]+\*?", "", num), denom)
        )

    # Evaluate the coefficients for each unknown and concatenate
    return left + " = " + " + ".join(
        (key + " * " + str(Fraction(sum(
            prod(map(float, num.split('*'))) / float(denom)
            for num, denom in expr
        )))).lstrip(" *")
        for key, expr in d.items()
    ).replace(" + -", " - ")

z_j_func = 'Z = 1 * 0 + 4 * 1/2 + 0 * 0 + 3 / 2 + M * 12 + M * 12 + M * 2 - 4 / 8'   
print(simplify(z_j_func))  # Z = M * 26 + 3
```